# Excel - Inserting years consecutively in row format without manually inputting it in

Tags: excel

Have a problem with excel. I have a lot of data that needs to be uploaded onto a site, however, the data provided for the years has a beginning year and an end year, but nothing in between. So for example, part XYZ fits vehicles from 2000-2004.

I wish to insert the remaining years (2001,2002 etc) years from 2000-2004 in row format. As the information is variable per catagory, it becomes problematic without a use of a formula to fill the gaps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you explain "row format" do you mean across as in `| 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 |` ?

Comment: More details on what end result you want please.

Comment: Hi, Doesnt necessarily need to be 5 serprate rows. Its ultimately going to be a CSV format so a single cell that contains all the dates would work just as aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will trim off the rest of the date from a value of `2000-2004` so that it reads `2000`:

`=LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-5)`

SO...if you have a column (A1 in this example) that has the date ranges, place this formula in B1 and you will get whatever the first 4 numbers are in cell A1.

Then in columns c1 you can simply add the formula `=sum(b1+1)` to get that date, plus one year. Then drag that formula out horizontally as far as you need.

Comment: Thanks, however, to do this for 8000 lines is very tedious as it doesnt simply work. Also the =sum(b1+1) doesnt work either as when you drag it across the row, the field changes to (c1+1), which essentially defeats the object. It would have to be =sum(b1+1) then next column sum=(b1+2) up until i get 2004, however as the dates are  quite extravagent, this wouldnt be feasible =(

Comment: actually, I did this for that simplification as b1 + 1 is the same as 2000 + 1  = 2001, and then the next column would be 2001 + 1 = 2002...  As for 8000 rows... not that hard if you simply take a few minutes or so to just drag the formula all the way down. In my trial I did it to 1000 rows and then 10 columns out and it took about 3 minutes to do.